# Using XCTFail when waiting on an expectation does not prevent timeout

Tags: xcode, xctest

When running an XCTest of an asynchronous operation, calling `XCTFail()` does not immediately fail the test, which was my expectation. Instead, whatever timeout period is remaining from the call to `wait` is first exhausted, which unnecessarily extends the test time and also creates a confusing failure message implying the test failed due to timeout, when in fact it explicitly failed.

```
func testFoo() {
    let x = expectation(description: "foo")

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        XCTFail("bar")
    }

    wait(for: [x], timeout: 5)
}
```

In the above example, although the the failure occurs after roughly 2 seconds, the test does not complete until the timeout period of 5 seconds has elapsed. When I first noticed this behavior I thought I was doing something wrong, but this seems to just be the way it works, at least with the current version of Xcode (9.2).

Since I didn't find any mention of this via google or stackoverflow searches, I'm sharing a workaround I found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered that the XCTestExpectation can still be fulfilled after calling `XCTFail()`, which does not count as a pass and immediately expires the `wait`. So, applying this to my initial example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    XCTFail("bar")
    x.fulfill()
}
```

This may be what Apple expects but it wasn't intuitive to me and I couldn't find it documented anywhere. So hopefully this saves someone else the time that I spent confused.

Comment: Yup. As I conclude in https://qualitycoding.org/asynchronous-tests/, the job of the block is to capture information, and trigger the fulfillment.

Comment: @JonReid Good writeup. Thanks for sharing! Only wish I would have found it sooner.